# Load content into div - close on 2nd click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have created a function to load content from a page into a `div` via ajax - that works quite nice using this function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$(".my-link-<?php the_ID(); ?>").click(function(){
var my_link = $(this).attr("href");
$("#single-post-container-<?php the_ID(); ?> ").html("video loading");
$("#single-post-container-<?php the_ID(); ?> ").load(my_link +' .video-container');
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

The content loads when I click on the title. But how can I add something that unloads/hides the content from the `div`, when I click the title a second time or I click a title from another post, to load content into a `div` for this post. Something like `addClass` ".hidden" would help - but how could I tell it with jquery?

Comment: Have you checked out the `.hide()` method of jQuery? `$('#idOfDivToHide').hide()` Or you could alter the display css property through a click event.

Comment: yes, but onClick it loads and hides the content. I think somewhere I need to add something like a stopper. But I am not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

u might want to move these lines outside of the click event to keep it from loading every time you click

```
var my_link = $(this).attr("href");
$("#single-post-container-<?php the_ID(); ?> ").html("video loading");
$("#single-post-container-<?php the_ID(); ?> ").load(my_link +' .video-container');

$("#single-post-container-<?php the_ID(); ?> ").hide();

$(".my-link-<?php the_ID(); ?>").click(function(){
      $("#single-post-container-<?php the_ID(); ?> ").toggle();
      return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks @jasper-giscombe. I changed the code - but I am not getting the data from the other post - toggle works, but is not loading the content.